# How can I mirror 2 tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

So, on my website I have a CPPS (Club Penguin Private Server), a blog & a forum. How can I mirror the tables so if I register an account for the blog, it'll work in the forum & CPPS or If I sign up for the CPPS, my account can be used in the blog & the forum.

I'm using myBB as the forum, Wordpress as the forum, and if you need the name of the source of which I'm using for the CPPS, tell me.

Comment: Can you not use the same database/table to refer to two different accounts? Possibly with account types?

Comment: @DarshanMehta That would mess up some stuff in the CPPS.

Comment: Sounds like an insert trigger might be what you're looking for

Comment: @SEarle1986 How do I do that?

Comment: Just posted the answer with how to do it

Answer (score 0):

In your source [blog] database add this trigger (Where your_table is the table you want to duplicate)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER duplicate_table_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO forum_db.your_table VALUES (new.col1,new.col2,new.col3); #etc...
END//
DELIMITER ;
```